# Meteor and cookies

Tags: cookies, meteor

Is there any way to use cookies in meteor?

I would like to have a per-machine id so I can handle license verifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

well, basically we used the jquery cookie plugin for that,
unfortunately there is no way to pass cookies from the server to the client directly so far (i guess you were thinking about something similar to the php cookie implementation).

i just use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie for this,
but you can also just use the builtin javascript cookie functions for that.

https://github.com/manarius/stellar/ feel free to have a look at stellar to see how we used cookies in there :)

have fun :)

manarius

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own question with localStorage.

There is no need for cookies in this scenario, just used localStorage to store the machine id and send it throw the Meteor.method call.

If older browsers are an issue, use localStorage.polyfill smart package.